# Why can't i assign the objects of the array inside ternary expression in C#?

Tags: c#

C#'s ternary expression is a little bit mysterious compared to ternary expressions in other languages. The problem is that i can not assign/reassign any objects of a particular array using ternary operators. The code that is demonstrated below doesn't work. It causes a compiler error. I know that is impossible to write something similar to the semantics mentioned above, but I really want to know the reason why C# wouldn't want to compile this piece of code.

```
string[] rawPath = new string[++levels];

for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++)
{
   i == 0 ? levelNotations[i] = path : levelNotations[i] = @"..";
}
```

Comment: this makes code hard to read.

Comment: You could always do `_ = i == 0 ? levelNotations[i] = 2 : levelNotations[i] = 1;`. Notice I said "could" and not "should."

Comment: A conditional operator (ternary) expression does not stand on its own as a statement.  As spoken by the Microsoft compiler (which you probably saw this message anyway: `CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`, *not* a ternary expression, even though its operand expressions are assignments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, there is a great distinction between *statements* and *expressions*. Some contexts expect only statements, and some contexts expect only expressions. Inside curly brackets for example (known as a "block"), you are expected to write statements.

```
i == 0 ? levelNotations[i] = path : levelNotations[i] = @".."
```

is an *expression*, not a statement. Only some, not all, expressions can be used as a statement by adding a `;` after them. These are called "statement expressions". A ternary operator expression (aka "conditional expression" in the language specification) is not a statement expression:

The list of statement expressions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#expression-statements) in the production rules for the C# grammar:

```
statement
    ...
    | embedded_statement
    ;

embedded_statement
    ...
    | expression_statement
    ...
    ;

expression_statement
    : statement_expression ';'
    ;

statement_expression
    : invocation_expression
    | null_conditional_invocation_expression
    | object_creation_expression
    | assignment
    | post_increment_expression
    | post_decrement_expression
    | pre_increment_expression
    | pre_decrement_expression
    | await_expression
    ;
```

Therefore, your code doesn't compile because it does not follow the syntax rules of C#.

You can instead write an *assignment* (`variable = expression`), which *is* a statement expression (see above), and use a ternary operator expression on the right hand side of the assignment:

```
levelNotations[i] = i == 0 ? path : @"..";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like in other languages, the association has to be defined before the ternary condition, not after.

```
string[] rawPath = new string[++levels];

for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++)
{
    levelNotations[i] = i == 0 ? path : @"..";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in using an if statement in this case:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++)
{
   if (i == 0) 
   {
       levelNotations[i] = path;
   }
   else
   {
       levelNotations[i] = @"..";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure. I was just interested in the reason as to why i can't do it otherwise. Thank you!